# Can't git in Pycharm 2017.3

Tags: git, powershell, pycharm

I'm using Powershell 5.1.6299.64 in

PyCharm 2017.3 (Professional Edition)

Build #PY-173.3727.137, built on November 28, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

on Windows 10

Git version is latest stable.

Getting this error when trying to rebase/update/checkout/whatever one branch onto other using built-in UI for managing Git:

```
core: runnerw.exe: cannot determine child command line from its parent:
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\PyCharm 2017.2.3\bin\runnerw.exe" 
"\"C:\Git\bin\git.exe\"" -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c core.commentChar= rebase origin/DEV
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in Settings -> Version Control -> Git.

The path was quoted: "C:\Git\cmd\git.exe" and that was the cause.

Reassigned the path to git executable to `C:\Git\cmd\git.exe` and now it works.